# App Icon Won't Change In iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons

I had an old app icon in xcode that I had just attached to the program to see how it looked in the simulator. I made changes, deleted the images, and replaced them in Xcode. However, they are still the old ones in the simulator. I tried resetting it and everything. Does it keep a cache somewhere?

EDIT: Solved by cleaning project.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning?

From the Xcode "Product" menu, choose "Clean" or "Clean Build Folder" if you hold alt/option.

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time Clean fixed my woes.

Comment: Sometimes `Clean` and `Clean Build Folder` don't do it for me. I have to remove the app folder from the iPhone Simulator. On my system this is at `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/{SOMEHASH}`. Look into each of the folders until you find your app. Then delete that folder. On the next start the new icon is used.

Comment: @RainerSchwarze another (easier) way to delete that folder is to delete the app from the Simulator.

Comment: @samvermette I tried that - it didn't work - the only working way for me was to remove that folder.

Answer (score 1):

If "Clean" does not work, try this:

- Reboot the device
- Kill the app before running it from Xcode.

Those works in my case.

Comment: I was having the problem with the cocos2d app icon wouldn't go away. In my case I had kill the app before running it (thank you), delete the app from my device/simulator, clean the project, and clean the folder. Doing these things individually didn't work. It had to be all of them at sequentially. Then ran the project and success! It wasn't working without the kill suggestion of yours for some crazy reason. +1'd you for that.

Comment: @AlienDev Good to hear that ;)